# Why is the download attribute no longer working after running my Django App in a docker image?

Tags: django, gunicorn

After running a docker image of my django app, I notice that downloading files is no longer available. The only thing I get is a copy of the website page I am currently on and not the requested file.

Locally, it is working fine.

Here is how my code is organized :

In **main/views.py** :

```bash
path_to_report = f"media/Reports/{request.user.username}/{request.user.username}{now.hour}{now.minute}{now.second}.txt" 


return render(request, "main/result.html", {"dic_files": dic_files, "nbr":len(files), "dic_small":dic_small, "dic_projects":dic_projects, "path_to_report":f"/app/{path_to_report}"})
```

In **main/result.html**

```html
<a href=/{{path_to_report}} download>

        <button class="btn btn-success" name="rapport" value="rapport"> Télécharger votre rapport</button>

</a>
```

Here is my **dockerfile** :

```bash
# Use the official lightweight Python image.

# https://hub.docker.com/_/python

FROM python:3.8



# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True



EXPOSE 8000



## api-transport-https installation

RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg



# Copy local code to the container image.

ENV APP_HOME /app

WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY . ./



# Install production dependencies.

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt



RUN python manage.py makemigrations

RUN python manage.py migrate

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input



ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "myteam.wsgi:application", "--bind=0.0.0.0:8000", "--workers=4", "--timeout=300", "--log-level=debug"]
```

Comment: Have you set up media files to be served at all?

Comment: Yes, MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL are all setup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your **main/views.py**, try replacing:

```bash
"path_to_report":f"/app/{path_to_report}"
```

with :

```bash
"path_to_report":path_to_report
```